# What is the Largest Negative Normalized Value in "decimal64" encoding?

Tags: floating-point, numbers, ieee-754

A teacher posed this question, along with a few others, in a lecture today and I was curious what the answer would be and the steps required to get the answer. Using the [IEEE-754 Base-10 Double standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on a 64-bit system. To clarify,  He said largest in value and smallest in magnitude as in closest to 0.

Thanks!

Comment: -2^63?????? although, what do you mean by `normalized`?????

Comment: normalized means that the exponent(11 bits in 64-bit systems) cannot be all 0's or 1's. From my understanding 1 bit is dedicated to the sign, 11-bits to the exp., and 52-bits to the fractional portion of the double.(in a 64-bit system.)

Comment: Could you explain why you think -2^63 is the answer? @barak

Comment: Now that you've mentioned `exponent`, I no longer think it's the answer

Comment: Would -1 be the answer? The sign bit would be 1, the exponent 00000000001 and the fractional portion all 0's.
@user2864740

Comment: @barakmanos: This is a floating-point question.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: It wasn't a `floating-point` question when I commented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link to Wikipedia you gave:

> The numbers −b^(1−emax) and b^(1−emax) ... are the smallest (in magnitude) normal numbers

In Decimal64, this is -10^(-383).

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes written with the notation `-1e-383`.